# Socket server in sails js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails.io.js

I have a mysql table that i am using to store data from an IOT device.The data is being sent in by the device after every 10 seconds. Basically,the sensors collect wind speed data and feed it directly to a remote mysql database table called `iotdata`

I want to build a server that reads `iotdata` after every 10 seconds and notify any connected client of the data received. Is it possible to build such a server within sails js?.

Comment: After a long search i have read this tutorial on how to do what i want. Here is the link http://blog.thesparktree.com/post/104779353989/reusing-sailsjs-waterline-models-in-background